# LyX system reconfiguration with SumatraPDF

Tags: latex, pdflatex, lyx, miktex

Installed SumatraPDF and am trying to reconfigure LyX to display with pdflatex. I am getting the following error using Tools > Reconfigure:

'The system reconfiguration has failed. Default textclass is used but LyX may not be able to work properly. Please reconfigure again if needed.'

Here are the steps I've attempted:

1. Under LyX Settings/Preferences > Paths > PATH prefix, add the path to SumatraPDF.exe. Then, under File Formats > Format: PDF (pdflatex) > Viewer, select SumatraPDF.
2. Under MikTeX Settings (Admin) (mo_admin.exe), select 'No' for 'Install missing packages on-the-fly'.

The error message remains the same each time.

While ViewPDF (pdflatex) does not open a window in SumatraPDF, it appears to create a PDF document which can be opened using SumatraPDF in a separate window.

I am using Windows 10 and have a default Python distribution 3.5.1.

Thanks!

(I'm new to LyX and to Stack Overflow so please be patient with me. Many thanks!)